# Getting Value of Table Cell to Depend on which Radio Buttons were Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some radio buttons, 10 in the first 5 cells of the row, which I would like to affect the value of the 6th cell in the row, for example, if the radio buttons '6, 7, 5, 8, 7' were clicked for each of the cells it would show the value 33, which is the sum of all 5 of those numbers, in the 'Overall' cell, here is my code so far:
BTW you have to see the results of the snippet in full page or it won't look correct.

```js
 // Save's the things the user entered
 document.getElementById('things').addEventListener('blur', function ( evt ) {
  window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked'] = this.value
 })

 // use the user’s saved things
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ( evt ) {
  var things = window.localStorage['things-to-be-picked']
  if ( things ) {
   document.getElementById('things').value = things
  }
 })
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 95%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table align=center>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Skating</th>
    <th>Shooting</th>
    <th>Passing</th>
    <th>Puck Control</th>
    <th>Team Play</th>
    <th>Overall</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <tr>
    <td>
    <form action="">
      <input type="radio"> 1
      <input type="radio"> 2
      <input type="radio"> 3
      <input type="radio"> 4
      <input type="radio"> 5<br>
      <input type="radio"> 6
      <input type="radio"> 7
      <input type="radio"> 8
      <input type="radio"> 9
      <input type="radio">10
    </form>
</td>
<td>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio"> 1
  <input type="radio"> 2
  <input type="radio"> 3
  <input type="radio"> 4
  <input type="radio"> 5<br>
  <input type="radio"> 6
  <input type="radio"> 7
  <input type="radio"> 8
  <input type="radio"> 9
  <input type="radio">10
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio"> 1
  <input type="radio"> 2
  <input type="radio"> 3
  <input type="radio"> 4
  <input type="radio"> 5<br>
  <input type="radio"> 6
  <input type="radio"> 7
  <input type="radio"> 8
  <input type="radio"> 9
  <input type="radio">10
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio"> 1
  <input type="radio"> 2
  <input type="radio"> 3
  <input type="radio"> 4
  <input type="radio"> 5<br>
  <input type="radio"> 6
  <input type="radio"> 7
  <input type="radio"> 8
  <input type="radio"> 9
  <input type="radio">10
</form>
</td>
<td>
<form action="">
  <input type="radio"> 1
  <input type="radio"> 2
  <input type="radio"> 3
  <input type="radio"> 4
  <input type="radio"> 5<br>
  <input type="radio"> 6
  <input type="radio"> 7
  <input type="radio"> 8
  <input type="radio"> 9
  <input type="radio">10
</form>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: where is the element with `id="things"`?

Comment: did you mean to affect the 6th column? And do you want only one option to be able to be selected per column/category?

Comment: @happymacarts Yes.

Comment: @sebasaenz All the JS does is save their radio selections just in case they accidentally reload the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only one value to be able to be selected on a radio group they all need to have the same name /per group [More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/radio)

I used `jQuery` for this since you had it tagged.

The `<form>` elements are not needed but i left them in place in case you need them for another purpose

I modified this to support multiple rows by adding the `class="item"` to each `<tr>`
I assume you plan to populate this info from a db or some automated loop the `data-id` attribute could be used also to capture unique info for each row should you need to target them uniquely later

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item'); 
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked")
    if (checkedItems.length > 4) {
      row.find("td.overall").html(getOvarall(checkedItems));
    }
  })

  function getOvarall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }


});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 95%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align=center>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Team Play</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1">1
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2">2
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3">3
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4">4
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5">5
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6">6
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7">7
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8">8
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9">9
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10">10
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way to not show the Overall until the person has selected a option from all of the categories? That way you can't accidentally miss one of the categories?

Comment: I left the office and am not going to test it from mobile, but you will need to modify the function to only return when all are not null. By adding an if clause in the change function

Comment: Not sure how to do that but okay. Also, what kind of modifications will have to be made?

Comment: I modified the function but I am on mobile so I cannot test to verify

Comment: Currently the code outputs the number is outputted after 4 radio buttons have been clicked, not 5, the number also won't change if you change your selection or click the 5th radio button, is this any help?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Check it now. I just modified the expression to >4 instead of ==4

Comment: Thanks for the help modifying it so that it can have multiple rows and so that it only shows the results after all 5 radio buttons have been clicked!